# How to export mysql database to another computer?

Tags: mysql, database, export, mysql-workbench

I created a database using Mysql Workbench. Now I want to export this database to my home PC.

How can I do this if the 2 PCs have no network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to export the database. You can use something like

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database name] > backup.sql
```

to store it in a file. After that you can import into another database via

```
mysql -u [username] -p [database name] < backup.sql
```

Comment: There's also a GUI option for this in MySQL workbench, just connect to the Server Administration GUI, then go to Import or Export in the sidebar

Comment: I used Import in sidebar, but how do I save the changes to model?

Answer (score 1):

As edit was rejected posting it as an answer; hope it will be helpful.
Followed to the queries give by "Marc Hauptmann" -

Few quick-tips for generic issues that can be faced while performing DB dump and restore:-

- As correctly mentioned above by "Marc" it is always advised not to provide db password in command line export [if you do so, it can be easily sniffed in history or reverse-search]
- If you are transferring large dump file it is advised to compress it before transferring. [it should be uncompressed before restore]
- While exporting if you want to export data with 'new database name' it can also be done. [It will require new Db to be created before using it in import]
- Also if we are exporting data from production servers to make sure it doesn't impact performance, export from other servers with below additional option "-h [hostname]"

*mysqldump -h [hostname] -u [username] -p [database name] > backup.sql*

Answer (score 0):

Using gzip is pretty painless and really shrinks these files.

`mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] | gzip -9 > [backupfile.sql.gz]`

`gunzip < [backupfile.sql.gz] | mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname]`

But man, it is 2014 - this stuff is also easy to do via a secure shell connection.